# logger print twice when using one logger

Tags: python

```
from logging import getLogger, INFO, StreamHandler, FileHandler, Formatter

log_file = 'test.txt'
logger = getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(INFO)
handler1 = StreamHandler()
handler1.setFormatter(Formatter('%(message)s'))
handler2 = FileHandler(filename = f'{log_file}.log')
handler2.setFormatter(Formatter('%(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler1)
logger.addHandler(handler2)


logger.info("HELLO")
```

> HELLO
> INFO:__main__: HELLO

I want to print only "HELLO" without the second print `INFO:__main__: HELLO`

How can I solve it?

( I ran the code in Colab. )

Comment: This code does not run. There is no INFO method in the logger class. Additionally, there is no `log_file` variable. My guess is that your Colab has state that you are unaware of. Is it possible to wipe the colab and start it from scratch?

Comment: `from logging import INFO` is on the first line.

Comment: That INFO is an enum that was used in the `logger.setLevel` line. Also you cannot import a method from a class. Try running your code in an online IDE instead of colab.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my mistake. I changed the `logger.info`. I start the code in colab from scratch, but the same result came out.

Comment: If you run this code in a fresh runtime, it will only print HELLO once, not twice.

Comment: It prints twice in the colab, but once in other IDE.. I mainly use colab, so I want it to print once in colab.

Comment: Then it must be something about colab itself and how it configures the runtime. Do you need the logging module in a colab? Would a print statement not do?

Comment: While training a ML model, I want to log information such as loss , metric, and time. This is the reason why I need logging.

Comment: It seems like the return value of the function. Try with `_ = logger.info("HELLO")`.

Comment: @accdias I tried it now, but the same result came out.

Comment: You can do all that with print statements. Up to you but logging is usually used to monitor the state and output of a long running program.

Comment: My code takes about 7~8 hours, so I want to leave a log in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `logger.propagate = False` to prevent logs from going up the chain to some ancestral handler, which I assume is what is happening here.